# What is the right way to get SignalR working on Xamarin mobile apps?

Tags: c#, xamarin, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm building [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) mobile applications and a SignalR Hub server.

I'm trying to incorporate SignalR sending and receiving in the Xamarin mobile apps.

[Some people](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2013/11/01/How-To-Use-SignalR-in-iOS-and-Android-Apps.aspx) are saying use the [signalr client nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/)

[Other people](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10107/signalr-component) are saying use the [dev branch of the signalR library](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/dev)

[Other people](http://blog.oxfordcc.co.uk/using-signalr-in-native-android-and-ios-apps/) are saying use the portable class library that comes in the xamarin branch of the SignalR library (not found, can only see [xamarin-package branch](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/xamarin-package))

I'm confused, I don't know what is the right way to get the latest versions of SignalR to work on Xamarin mobile apps with SignalR Hub servers

Please advise

Comment: I remember looking for this a while back and it was highly discouraged: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10107/signalr-component

Comment: any more help/info guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "[Some people](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2013/11/01/How-To-Use-SignalR-in-iOS-and-Android-Apps.aspx) are saying use the signalr client nuget package"

worked best!

just followed the tutorial on visualstudiomagazine and all worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

this trick work for me 
1)make a simple demo project like winform
2) download the new latest signalr client from nuget
3) copy the

> Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.dll
>   from folder
>   Yourproject\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.2.0.1\lib\portable-net45+sl5+netcore45+wp8

4) paste this dll file into ur xamarin project folder anywhere

finally add this to ur project by simmply adding referance